# Node request fails with socket hang up

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a consistent problem with using the request module where, regardless of the URL I provide, I am getting a socket hang up error, generally a connection reset.  What makes this more strange is that this code works on another developers machine without problem.

```
var request = require("request");


request("http://google.com", function(error, response, body) {

    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);

  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {


  }
});
```

This is a simplified version of the code but it illustrates the point.  If I do something like this though

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80
};

http.get(options, function (resp) {
    var bdy = "";
    resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
        bdy = bdy + chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', function () {
        //var r = JSON.parse(bdy);
        console.log(bdy);
    }); 
}).on("error", function (e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

I get a response back from Google as I would expect.  What is strange is that both the request module and another module I am using (weather-js) exhibiting the same behavior: all requests result in some sort of socket error.  Additionally, when I run Fiddler I can see the `http.get` request go out, but I never see an entry when the code from the `request` or `weather-js` module runs.

I am running Node 10.5.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: `this code works on another developers machine` does he also use Windows 10 and same node version? Also, have you tried other libs (like axios)?

Comment: It works on both macOS and Windows using 10.x and 8.x versions of node.  I haven't tried any other libs though.